# Laravel 5.5 Routing and Sub-domain Routing

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am very new in Laravel. I currently created my personal site on Laravel 5.5 and uploaded to GoDaddy server: http://bhattraideb.com/. Now when I click on 'Blog' from navigation I would like to redirect like  http://blog.bhattraideb.com/ which is currently redirection to '**bhattraideb.com/public/blog**'.

Again from the same this link '**bhattraideb.com/public/blog**' when I click on 'Resume' I aspect to redirect on '**bhattraideb.com/**'

Here is my route code

//** Resume Routes

```
Route::prefix('/')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'Frontend\ResumeController@index')->name('resume.index');
    Route::resource('resume', 'Frontend\ResumeController');
});
```

//**  Blog Routes

```
Route::get('show/{id}', 'Frontend\PostController@show')->name('post.show');
Route::get('blog/{slug}', ['as' => 'post.single', 'uses' => 'Frontend\PostController@getSingle'])->where('slug', '[\w\d-\_]+');
Route::resource('blog', 'Frontend\PostController');
```

Can anyone please guide me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing for more details on this but the following simple example should work:

**web.php**

```
Route::group(["domain" => "blog.bhattraideb.com" ], function () {
     Route::get("/", "Frontend\PostController")->name("blog.index"); 
     //All blog routes should be defined in here
});
```

You can then use the helper `route("blog.index")` to get the URL along with the subdomain when generating links to the blog.

Note that you will need to setup the webserver to accept `blog.bhattraideb.com` as an alias of `bhattraideb.com`. Laravel will then sort the rest out